# Adding row data at the top row using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code, what it is doing right now is adding data to the table? Here it the [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/49/)..I have the table with data already..when I add another item it should add as a first row...right now it is adding after the existing data..any suggestions..

```
EDIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#datatable").prepend(tr);`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/M8MHc/)

Comment: awesome it is working now..How to clear the input value once I click the submit button??

Comment: After retrieve the $("#number").val(), just do a $("#number").val(""); this will set the input to a empty string.

Comment: cool it is working fine..What I am trying to do is I added two buttons which are disabled by default.when I add an item the buttons will enable once I click receipt button the checkbox checked should go away which is working in my laptop but not in fiddle and also if i click receipt it should the removeAttr checked to the check box and the buttons should disable because no checkbox is checked..here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/M8MHc/8/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

> The .prepend() method inserts the specified content as the first child of each element in the jQuery collection (To insert it as the last child, use .append()).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#datatable").prepend(tr);
```

instead of

```
$("#datatable").append(tr);
```

in line 12.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepend instead of append.

```
$("#datatable").prepend(tr);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e254w/49/)**